# Handling Kotlin Serialization MissingFieldException with Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, kotlinx.serialization

I'm using [kotlinx.serialization](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) in conjunction with [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). The json response that I receive will vary in terms of what attributes it will contain. In most cases, the data model in my app has more fields than I will receive in the response. I cannot control this, so I need to handle it in code.

Kotlinx.serialization throws a `MissingFieldException` in such cases. I know that when using `Json.parse` you can wrap it in a try-catch block and ignore such errors. But since I am using Retrofit, I don't see a way to use that approach:

WebService.kt

```
interface WebService {
    @GET("person.json")
    fun getPerson(): Call<MainActivity.Person>
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Serializable
    data class Person(val name: String, val species: String, val missing: String)

    @UnstableDefault
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val mediaType = "application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull()
        mediaType?.let {
            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(Json.nonstrict.asConverterFactory(it))
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .build()
        }

        webService = retrofit.create(WebService::class.java)

        GlobalScope.launch {
            val person = fetchPerson(webService)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun fetchPerson(webService: WebService): Person {
        return suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
            webService.getPerson()
                .enqueue(object : Callback<Person> {
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<Person>, t: Throwable) {
                        Log.e(t.toString(), "Unable to get api response")
                        cont.cancel(t)
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<Person>,
                        response: Response<Person>
                    ) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            response.body()?.let { cont.resume(it) }
                        } else {
                            cont.cancel(IOException("${response.code()}: ${response.errorBody()}"))
                        }
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}
```

The json response (in this made up example) intentionally omits the 'missing' field:

```
{"name":"me", "species":"superhuman"}
```

Since that json does not contain the `missing` field from the data class, the app crashes and throws the `MissingFieldException`. I'm wondering how to avoid this issue in the Retrofit case.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you please try to add default value in your `Person` data model. Hope this will help you

Comment: That worked, but I'm hoping for something that won't require me to set default values across all of my data models. The real world application is MUCH more complex. If you post this as an answer, and I don't get a better one, then I'll accept this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually it can't create `Person` object from json as your `Person` class constructor wants 3 value. You have to fulfill this requirement to create object.

One possible solution to resolve this is to use default value in **Kotlin** like this:

```
data class Person(
    var name: String="", 
    var species: String="", 
    var missing: String="")
```

Another solution is to use multiple constructor with varying no of parameters but since you mentioned it may differ over time, so this solution may not handy. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I may have to resort to this eventually. I'm hoping to find a setting that will relax this requirement. For example, Gson has no such requirement. If I do wind up using this, I will accept this answer.

Comment: Sure, no problem. You can also try `vararg` for similar types of parameter, though it loses key->value facilities

Answer (score 3):

Starting from `kotlinx.serialization-1.3.0`, you can create the Json object as `Json { explicitNulls = false }`. This will help in serializing response with varying fields without throwing the `MissingFieldException` and without the need of passing default values.

[Reference](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/releases/tag/v1.3.0-RC)

Answer (score 0):

For others who has already made the property as nullable and still get the issue, set `explicitNulls to false` in your JsonBuilder

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
val CustomJson = Json {
    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    isLenient = true
    explicitNulls = false
}

// usage
CustomJson.decodeFromString<Class>(jsonString)
```

[image]